# How to build a machine learning system (smart system) that updates automatically?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-analysis

I am kinda a newbie in machine learning. I have done lots of learning related to data analysis and ML algorithms, and I've got very good results and understanding of the algorithms. However, my approaches are normally *getting datasets, writing scripts or notebooks to solve the problems* and that's pretty much it. Which means, **no matter how fancy I create a script, I have to run the script everytime for each update, this is not enough.**

I think that machine learning is more than that, and there are already smart systems that are constantly updating their systems automatically, and I am really interested in that, but can't really find any good materials that dive deep into that field.

> Let's just say, like the classic example, there's a website that has a ML system at the backend that identifies iris categories, and it's visitors constantly upload new observations of irises and the visitors get the category of the iris they upload, and the backend system continues to improve accordingly.

How can I get to learn thing like this? Would be super keen to dive into this field.

I'd really appreciate all your opinions!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is not a stackoverflow question. Post it in stats. Quick answer: there are different kinds of algorithms, you are talking about online learning algorithms. But it is not uncommon for sites to just use non-online algorithms and just update their models every once in a while.

Comment: Go read up on reinforcement learning. Bayesian networks are built on that premise.

Answer (score 1):

you are asking "Incremental way of learning " !!

it's depends on what task are you doing. you can not apply incremental learning everywhere. the real problem is when we train , in the process of training , there are many other things that are related(inter dependent). which gets changed during a new cycle.

so if you can make your algorithm independent , then you can do "incremental way of learning" !!

Answer (score 0):

Machine learning is not a simple art.  It requires a good understanding of multi-variable calculus and linear algebra (matrices).  I am no ML expert but I love the topic.  If you are serious about learning I would recommend taking a good intro course like this one: https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning